# Помогите оптимизировать SQL запрос

Tags: sql

Тормозящий запрос выглядит примерно так:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT key3, key1 FROM table2 ) t2 USING (key1)
    INNER JOIN table3 USING (key3)
```

Тормозит из-за DISTINCT, который необходим, т.к. в таблице table2 на один key1 несколько записей с key3, а нужна в итоге одна строчка. 
Реально запрос еще сложнее, к таблицам 1 и 3 по ключам прицеплено еще куча всего, но если убрать distinct - тормоза выключают. Пробовал вместо DISTINCT - GROUP BY  - не помогло.

Comment: А индекс `table2(key3, key1)` - имеется? Если нет - создайте.

Comment: Составной?  Небыло, были только отдельно по ключам. Создал - не помогло (

Comment: Какая именно СУБД? Производительность абстрактного sql крутить гиблое дело. И, конечно, нужен результат `explain` и ddl таблиц с индексами

Answer (score 1):

Информации мало, но если я правильно понял, то Вам следует группировать уже результат. Вот пример :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    table2.key1
FROM table1
    JOIN table2 ON table1.key1 = table2.key1
    JOIN table3 ON table2.key3 = table3.key3
```

Дополните свой вопрос и покажите что вы хотите видеть в результате.

Comment: Спасибо. Вот это помогло. Я,естественно, пробовал группировать результат. Но вот так 

    SELECT * FROM table1
        INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT key3, key1 FROM table2 ) t2 
    USING (key1)
        INNER JOIN table3 USING (key3)

А это не помогало, естественно